# Why doesn't my code on Jupyter produce an output

Tags: python, jupyter

```
given_list = [7, 5, 4, 4, 3, 1, -2, -3, -5, -7]

total = 0 
i = 0
while i < len(given_list) and given_list[i] <= 0: 
    total += given_list[i]
    i += 1
    print(total)
```

I'm using Jupyter notebook and following the tutorials for python by CSdojo on youtube. I was wondering why when I run my code, the cell after it does not produce an output (total)?

Comment: `given_list[i]` where `i` is `0` resolves to `7` which means that your while loop doesn't even start as one of the conditions is `given_list[i] <= 0`. Clearly, `7` is not less or equal to zero.

Comment: That's a very awkward way to achieve that. Consider `sum(n for n in given_list if n <= 0)`

Comment: @DeepSpace `sum(n for n in given_list if n < 0)` is slightly shorter and faster :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Dang it :D

Comment: @DeepSpace "nitpick" is my middle name :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `given_list[i] <= 0`.

First `i = 0` then `given_list[i] = 7`

7 is not equal or less than 0, then `True and False` evaluates to `False`. That's why it doesn't show output.
In this case you don't have any problem with Jupyter or Python. Your problem was your logic. Please try hard in algorithm not syntax.